# How to solve if `RotatingServerAdvice` is not fetching file for multiple times?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I am using `IntegrationFlow` as **Sftp Inbound DSL Configuration** where I am using `CustomTriggerAdvice` to handle manual trigger. Please see below code snippet for reference.

I am also using `RotatingServerAdvice` for handling multiple path in same host.

But when I start the **Sftp Inbound** it fetch file for the first time from every path but it does not work for second time and onward. *Sftp Inbound Starts but does not fetch file from paths.* I couldn't figure out the problem. Is there anything that I am missing?

**`SftpConfiguration`**

```
public IntegrationFlow fileFlow() {
    SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec spec = Sftp
            .inboundAdapter(dSF())
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
            .remoteDirectory(".")
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
            .localDirectory(new File(getDestinationLocation()));

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(spec, e -> e.id(BEAN_ID)
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .poller(Pollers
                            .fixedDelay(5000)
                            .advice(
                                    customRotatingServerAdvice(dSF()),
                                    customTriggerAdvice()
                            )
                    )
            )
            .channel(sftpReceiverChannel())
            .handle(sftpInboundMessageHandler())
            .get();
}

private MessageChannel sftpReceiverChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
```

... ... ...

```
@Bean
public RotatingServerAdvice customRotatingServerAdvice(
      DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> dSF
) {
    List<String> pathList = getSourcePathList();
    for (String path : pathList) {
        keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory(KEY, path));
    }

    return new RotatingServerAdvice(
            dSF,
            keyDirectories
    );
}

@Bean
public CustomTriggerAdvice customTriggerAdvice() {
    return new CustomTriggerAdvice(customControlChannel(),BEAN_ID);
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow customControlBus() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(customControlChannel())
            .controlBus()
            .get();
}


@Bean
public MessageChannel customControlChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
```

**`CustomTriggerAdvice`**

```
public class CustomTriggerAdvice extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {
    private final MessageChannel controlChannel;
    private final String BEAN_ID;

    public CustomTriggerAdvice(MessageChannel controlChannel, String beanID) {
        this.controlChannel = controlChannel;
        this.BEAN_ID = beanID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
        if (result == null) {
            controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@" + BEAN_ID + ".stop()"));
        } 
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Starting Sftp Inbound using MessageChannel**

```
@Qualifier("customControlChannel") MessageChannel controlChannel;


public void startSftpInbound(){
       controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@" + beanID + ".start()"));
}
```

Comment: Your `CustomTriggerAdvice` stops your `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` with `BEAN_ID` for your `SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec`, but I don't see where you call that `startSftpInbound()`...

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I am calling it to anther service.

Comment: So, what do you expect then? You stop it when no new files and you definitely need to start it again eventually to be able to pick new files up. If there are still no new files on the restart, it is going to stop again. That's your logic. Not sure what you are looking for...

Comment: Yes, you are right. But when I am restarting the **Sftp Inbound** using `startSftpInbound()` it is restarting but it is not fetching new files.

Comment: Are you sure that you have new files in your remote folders and their names don't clash with already fetched? The `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` is configured with the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` by default to avoid refetching files with the same name and timestamp. You need to investigate logs in DEBUG level to be sure what is going on.

Comment: I have tried all kinds of **DEBUG** and I couldn't find anything and quite sure that the file is not is not fetched before and file is not stored in the `MetadataStore`.

Comment: OK. How does it work if you remove your `customTriggerAdvice()`? Kinda let's try to narrow the boundaries for the problem

Comment: It works as usual. It fetches new file within a moment after polling each path.

Comment: OK. Can you now to stop and restart that channel adapter to be sure that the problem with rotation is really because we stop in between?

Comment: Are you asking me to stop the **Sftp Inbound** manually instead of using it in `afterReceive()`?

Comment: Right. That's what I want to see. Please, stop it after fetching some files. Ten restart it back to be sure where we are.

Comment: Yes . Its working when I removed `controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@" + BEAN_ID + ".stop()"));` from `afterReceive()` its restarting and fetching new files. I used manual trigger for stopping **Sftp Inbound**.

Comment: Hope you got my logic and how I want to use stop **Sftp Inbound** after polling every directory at least one time.

Comment: Well, your logic is a bit not stable: when the first server doesn't have files to poll, it returns `null` for the advice and stop polling over here without any chances to let another server to take a look into its files. We definitely don't poll all the servers at once: we move to the next one only on the next poll. Also pay attention to the `fair` option of the `RotatingServerAdvice`.

Comment: Well, I got your point. I also tried with `fair` option. But I need the system to start on demand and fetch file completing one cycle. If it is not stopped after that, it will continue polling and won't stop and my system will fall into an infinite loop. Is there any way to get that when the `RotatingServerAdvice`  is completing polling from all servers at least one? Does it throw any event or something like that ? Otherwise I have to stop here with **Sftp Inbound Adapter**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the system to start on demand and fetch file completing one cycle. If it is not stopped after that, it will continue polling and won't stop and my system will fall into an infinite loop. Is there any way to get that when the RotatingServerAdvice is completing polling from all servers at least one? Does it throw any event or something like that ?

You probably misunderstood the logic with the `afterReceive(@Nullable Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source)` contract. You can't stop a channel adapter for your requirements when one of the servers has returned nothing to poll. This way you don't give a chance for another server to poll on the next polling cycle.

I think your idea is to iterate over all the servers only once and then stop. Probably independently of the result from any of them. It looks like the best way to stop for you it is to use a `RotatingServerAdvice` with the `fair = true` to move to the next server every time. The stop might be performed from the custom `afterReceive()` independently of the result when you see that the `RotationPolicy.getCurrent()` is equal to a last one in the list. So, this way you iterate over all of them and stop moving the first one for the next poling cycle.

Comment: Do `afterReceive()` have anything like  `RotationPolicy.getCurrent()`? Or where to find this `RotationPolicy.getCurrent()` ?

Comment: The `RotatingServerAdvice` has the `rotationPolicy` property. You need a custom `RotatingServerAdvice` with `afterReceive()` overridden to perform a logic to be sure that you are in a state to stop a channel adapter.